# Azure web site reserved mode load balancing seems to not work

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I am in Free or Shared Website mode (with an instance count of 2), and I delete the ARRAffinity cookie then I can see that it will swap between the two different instances running. To double check this I also display the machine name on the website.

However when running in Reserved mode with 2 or more instances I always get directed to the same machine. It doesn't matter if I delete the Cookies or hit the site from a different machine / ip I always go to the same machine with the same ARRAffinity cookie.

It looks to me like the load balancing isn't working properly in reserved mode, or perhaps I don't understand the way the load balancer works?

If this is expected behaviour then how can I tell if the other instances are actually running?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't much of articles on Azure Web Sites running in reserved mode behind load-balancer. The important aspect of understanding a load balancer is its algorithm. Here we are not sure whether the Load Balancer is using a session sticky or round robin or at least not sure whether the routing depends the ARRAffinity cookie.

The way what I recommend to check it do a load test (a heavy one) and see the logs on each of the machine. The Reserved mode must the best of the given load balancers of all other website modes and also Azure Website instances as they are named "Reserved" and assured of guaranteed infra.

One more catch what I sense, the way the free & shared Websites load balancers might be designed differently than the reserved ones.

If nothing works out, raise a support ticket to see ask them what is happening and perhaps share their responses here.

Comment: I've turned on logging and will do some heavy load tests to see what happens. I'll report back when done.

Answer (score 0):

Nir Mashkowski, Program Manager Lead for Azure Web Sites, presents a great "Web Sites Internals" [webcast session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Internals-with-Nir-Mashkowski) session on Channel9. This talk goes into low-level detail around Web Sites architecture, including all the components in Web Sites (such as IIS ARR).

Web Sites, as a *service*, takes care of load-balancing, instance health, etc. There's no stated load-balancing method, although Nir talks about asp.net sticky-sessions (meaning routing to the same instance). Session data would need to remain in a shared resource.

Hopefully this content gives you the info you need...